# Default Value for qmap optional parameter

Tags: c++, default, option-type, qmap

I'm working in C++ and want to create a function with an optional parameter that is a QMap.  The question is what do I set the default value to.  I want it to be an empty map.

```
void function(int i, QMap< QString, QString > MyMap = ???)
```

what do you put for ???

Answer (score 4):

Question:

> what do you put for ???

1. You can put a default constructed object.

   ```
   void function(int i, QMap< QString, QString > MyMap = QMap<QString, QString>())
   ```
2. You can put a call to a function that returns a compatible object.

   ```
   QMap< QString, QString > const& foo();
   void function(int i, QMap< QString, QString > MyMap = foo())
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pointer to QMap (QMap*) and give it the NULL value as default:

```
void function(int i, QMap< QString, QString > *MyMap = NULL)
{

}
```